# Книги по JasperReports

Tags: java, книги

Подскажите литературу по JasperReports, книги, сайты.

Comment: На английском сойдёт?

Comment: я другой и не встречал, кроме ответов на форумах

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ряд статей тут: [цикл статей о JasperReports](http://voituk.kiev.ua/intro-jasper-reports/). Книжки... JasperReports 3.5 for Java Developers (+ примеры).

Comment: интересно, спасибо